# Getting Policy Falsified <l7:policyResult status="Authentication Required" xmlns:l7="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>

Tags: rest, ssl, https, soapui, apache-httpclient-4.x

When calling a REST Service from my program, I am getting 500 Internal Server Error, but calling the same service From SOAPUI is working.

**My Observations:**

1. With SOAP UI, I am sending request only once, but logs show two requests - first request fails with 401 Unauthorized; Second request adds Authorization Header
2. With TestMainOne Program, I tried to simulate what SOAP UI was doing by sending two requests, I got 500 Internal Server error both times instead of 401.
3. With TestMainTwo Program, I got "Authentication succeeded" but I also got 500 Internal Server Error.

### My Questions

1. How do I simulate what SOAP UI is doing (exactly)?
2. For the same request, what could be the reason for 500 Internal Server Error (instead of 401)?
3. Why it fails with "Authentication Required", when I am clearly sending "Authorization" header?

### SOAP UI

1. Created a REST Project
2. Added jks file
3. In request properties supplied username & password

### SOAP UI Log: (Working - I could see my expected json response)

```
>> "POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 92[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: devint.test.intranet[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> "{"payLoad":{"REQUEST":{"PROCESS_NM":"ORDER_ID"},"ITEMS":{"0":{"ORDER_ID":"ABC1"}}}}"


<< "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
<< "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
<< "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="L7SSGBasicRealm"[\r][\n]"
<< "L7-Policy-URL: https://devint.test.intranet:443/ssg/policy/disco?serviceoid=83f02502063fbaf43344f0c0888e3821[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Length: 23[\r][\n]"
<< "Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:17:09 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
<< "Authentication Required"

>> "POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 92[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: devint.test.intranet[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
>> "Authorization: Basic RVNMQ1hHNzpvVnlGUjNFNXMxQU41NnBJTXFOSCE=[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> "{"payLoad":{"REQUEST":{"PROCESS_NM":"ORDER_ID"},"ITEMS":{"0":{"ORDER_ID":"ABC1"}}}}"
<< "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
<< "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
<< "Jmscorrelationidasbytes: Camel-ID-NE1ITCDRHAS09-ne1-savvis-net-39938-1486746426315-0-94041[\r][\n]"
<< "Jmstimestamp: 1489544237805[\r][\n]"
<< "Jmsdestination: temp-queue://ID:NE1ITCDRHAS09.ne1.savvis.net-40529-1486746732513-1:914:1[\r][\n]"
<< "Jmsexpiration: 0[\r][\n]"
<< "Jmsdeliverymode: 1[\r][\n]"
<< "Jmsmessageid: ID:NE1ITCDRHAS09.ne1.savvis.net-36391-1489532794035-1:1:1:1:1[\r][\n]"
<< "Jmscorrelationid: Camel-ID-NE1ITCDRHAS09-ne1-savvis-net-39938-1486746426315-0-94041[\r][\n]"
<< "Jmspriority: 4[\r][\n]"
<< "Jmsredelivered: false[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Length: 495[\r][\n]"
<< "Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:17:17 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
<< "<Encrypted Ouyput>"
```

TestMainOne

```
public class TestMainOne {      
    private static final String RESPONSE_TYPE_JSON = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    private static String getTextSearchResults(String restWebServiceURL) {
            try {                   
                String jksFile = "C:\\Users\\temp\\Desktop\\Cert\\ABC1-cxg-test2.jks";
                String jksFilePassword = "!jkspassword700";
                String username = "<username>";
                String password = "<password>";                 
                File file = new File(jksFile);
                SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                        .loadTrustMaterial(file, jksFilePassword.toCharArray(),
                                new TrustStrategy() {                       
                            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {                     
                                return true;
                            }
                        })
                        .build();                   
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" }, null, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
                CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(restWebServiceURL);
                String requestString = "{\"payLoad\":{\"REQUEST\":{\"PROCESS_NM\":\"GetOrdersHierarchy\"},\"ITEMS\":{\"0\":{\"ORDER_ID\":\"ABC1\"}}}}";
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestString);
                entity.setContentType(RESPONSE_TYPE_JSON);
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"L7SSGBasicRealm\"");
                System.out.println("Test 4 First Response: " + String.valueOf(response));
                byte[] credentialsByte = Base64.encodeBase64((username + ":" + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(credentialsByte, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                System.out.println("Test 4 Second Response: " + String.valueOf(response));
                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    System.out.println("Error While Calling Web restWebServiceURL: " + restWebServiceURL + " HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                }else{                  
                    json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    logger.("json: " + json);                                   
                }                   
            } catch (Exception e) {             
                System.out.println("Exception While Calling Web restWebServiceURL: " + restWebServiceURL + ", Exception: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
        return json;
    }       
}
```

TestMainOne Output

```
   RequestAddCookies:123 - CookieSpec selected: default
   RequestAuthCache:77 - Auth cache not set in the context
   PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:255 - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://devint.test.intranet:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
   PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:288 - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://devint.test.intranet:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
   MainClientExec:235 - Opening connection {s}->https://devint.test.intranet:443
   DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:139 - Connecting to devint.test.intranet/155.70.58.219:443
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:337 - Connecting socket to devint.test.intranet/155.70.58.219:443 with timeout 0
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:390 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:391 - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, ... TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:395 - Starting handshake
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:425 - Secure session established
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:426 -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:427 -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:435 -  peer principal: CN=cxg7o.test.centurylink.com, OU=IT, O=CenturyLink, L=Monroe, ST=Louisiana, C=US
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:444 -  peer alternative names: [cxg7o.test.centurylink.com, cxg7o.test.qintra.com]
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:448 -  issuer principal: CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
   DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:146 - Connection established 10.1.209.211:65485<->155.70.58.219:443
   MainClientExec:256 - Executing request POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1
   MainClientExec:261 - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
   MainClientExec:267 - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED


   headers:133 - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 92
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: devint.test.intranet
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_102)
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 92[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: devint.test.intranet[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_102)[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
   wire:87 - http-outgoing-0 >> "{"payLoad":{"REQUEST":{"PROCESS_NM":"GetOrdersHierarchy"},"ITEMS":{"0":{"ORDER_ID":"ABC1"}}}}"


   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "L7-Policy-URL: https://devint.test.intranet:443/ssg/policy/disco?serviceoid=83f02502063fbaf43344f0c0888e3821[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 582[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:21:38 GMT[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "    <soapenv:Body>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "        <soapenv:Fault>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "            <faultstring>Policy Falsified</faultstring>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "            <faultactor>https://devint.test.intranet/X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV</faultactor>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "            <detail>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "                <l7:policyResult status="Authentication Required" xmlns:l7="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "            </detail>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "        </soapenv:Fault>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "    </soapenv:Body>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "</soapenv:Envelope>[\n]"
   headers:122 - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << L7-Policy-URL: https://devint.test.intranet:443/ssg/policy/disco?serviceoid=83f02502063fbaf43344f0c0888e3821
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 582
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:21:38 GMT
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: close
Test 4 First Response: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, L7-Policy-URL: https://devint.test.intranet:443/ssg/policy/disco?serviceoid=83f02502063fbaf43344f0c0888e3821, Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 582, Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:21:38 GMT, Connection: close, WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="L7SSGBasicRealm"] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8,Content-Length: 582,Chunked: false]}}
   RequestAddCookies:123 - CookieSpec selected: default
   RequestAuthCache:77 - Auth cache not set in the context
   PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:255 - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://devint.test.intranet:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
   PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:288 - Connection leased: [id: 1][route: {s}->https://devint.test.intranet:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 2 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
   MainClientExec:235 - Opening connection {s}->https://devint.test.intranet:443
   DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:139 - Connecting to devint.test.intranet/155.70.58.219:443
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:337 - Connecting socket to devint.test.intranet/155.70.58.219:443 with timeout 0
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:390 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:391 - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, ... TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:395 - Starting handshake
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:425 - Secure session established
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:426 -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:427 -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:435 -  peer principal: CN=cxg7o.test.centurylink.com, OU=IT, O=CenturyLink, L=Monroe, ST=Louisiana, C=US
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:444 -  peer alternative names: [cxg7o.test.centurylink.com, cxg7o.test.qintra.com]
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:448 -  issuer principal: CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
   DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:146 - Connection established 10.1.209.211:65486<->155.70.58.219:443
   MainClientExec:256 - Executing request POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1
   MainClientExec:267 - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
   headers:133 - http-outgoing-1 >> POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> Authorization: Basic RVNMQ1hHNzpvVnlGUjNFNXMxQU41NnBJTXFOSCE=
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Length: 92
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> Host: devint.test.intranet
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_102)
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Authorization: Basic RVNMQ1hHNzpvVnlGUjNFNXMxQU41NnBJTXFOSCE=[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Length: 92[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Host: devint.test.intranet[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_102)[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
   wire:87 - http-outgoing-1 >> "{"payLoad":{"REQUEST":{"PROCESS_NM":"GetOrdersHierarchy"},"ITEMS":{"0":{"ORDER_ID":"ABC1"}}}}"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "L7-Policy-URL: https://devint.test.intranet:443/ssg/policy/disco?serviceoid=83f02502063fbaf43344f0c0888e3821[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "Content-Length: 582[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:21:38 GMT[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "    <soapenv:Body>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "        <soapenv:Fault>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "            <faultstring>Policy Falsified</faultstring>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "            <faultactor>https://devint.test.intranet/X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV</faultactor>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "            <detail>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "                <l7:policyResult status="Authentication Required" xmlns:l7="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "            </detail>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "        </soapenv:Fault>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "    </soapenv:Body>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "</soapenv:Envelope>[\n]"
   headers:122 - http-outgoing-1 << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << L7-Policy-URL: https://devint.test.intranet:443/ssg/policy/disco?serviceoid=83f02502063fbaf43344f0c0888e3821
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << Content-Length: 582
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:21:38 GMT
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << Connection: close
Test 4 Second Response: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, L7-Policy-URL: https://devint.test.intranet:443/ssg/policy/disco?serviceoid=83f02502063fbaf43344f0c0888e3821, Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 582, Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:21:38 GMT, Connection: close] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8,Content-Length: 582,Chunked: false]}}
Error While Calling Web restWebServiceURL: https://devint.test.intranet/X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP error code : 500
Exception While Calling Web restWebServiceURL: https://devint.test.intranet/X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV, Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 500
    at TestMain2.getTextSearchResults(TestMain2.java:132)
    at TestMain2.main(TestMain2.java:69)
```

TestMainTwo

```
public class TestMainTwo {          
    private static final String RESPONSE_TYPE_JSON = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    private static String getTextSearchResults(String restWebServiceURL) {
        String json ="";
        try {
                String jksFile = "C:\\Users\\temp\\Desktop\\Cert\\ABC1-cxg-test2.jks";
                String jksFilePassword = "!jkspassword700";
                String username = "<username>";
                String password = "<password>";
                File file = new File(jksFile);
                SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                        .loadTrustMaterial(file, jksFilePassword.toCharArray(),
                                new TrustStrategy() {                       
                            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {                     
                                return true;
                            }
                        })
                        .build();

                SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" }, null, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);        

                HttpHost target = new HttpHost("devint.test.intranet", 443, "https");
                CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
                provider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
                        credentials);
                AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
                BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
                authCache.put(target, basicAuth);            
                HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
                localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);
                CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
                        .build();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(restWebServiceURL);
                String requestString = "{\"payLoad\":{\"REQUEST\":{\"PROCESS_NM\":\"GetOrdersHierarchy\"},\"ITEMS\":{\"0\":{\"ORDER_ID\":\"ABC1\"}}}}";
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestString);
                entity.setContentType(RESPONSE_TYPE_JSON);
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(target,httpPost,localContext);
                System.out.println("Test 4 First Response: " + String.valueOf(response));
            } catch (Exception e) {             
                System.out.println("Exception While Calling Web restWebServiceURL: " + restWebServiceURL + ", Exception: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            }           
        return json;
    }   
}
```

TestMainTwo Output

```
  RequestAddCookies:123 - CookieSpec selected: default
  RequestAuthCache:131 - Re-using cached 'basic' auth scheme for https://devint.test.intranet:443
  PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:255 - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://devint.test.intranet:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
  PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:288 - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://devint.test.intranet:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
  MainClientExec:235 - Opening connection {s}->https://devint.test.intranet:443
  DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:139 - Connecting to devint.test.intranet/155.70.58.219:443
  SSLConnectionSocketFactory:337 - Connecting socket to devint.test.intranet/155.70.58.219:443 with timeout 0
  SSLConnectionSocketFactory:390 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
  SSLConnectionSocketFactory:391 - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, ... TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
  SSLConnectionSocketFactory:395 - Starting handshake
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:425 - Secure session established
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:426 -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:427 -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:435 -  peer principal: CN=cxg7o.test.centurylink.com, OU=IT, O=CenturyLink, L=Monroe, ST=Louisiana, C=US
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:444 -  peer alternative names: [cxg7o.test.centurylink.com, cxg7o.test.qintra.com]
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory:448 -  issuer principal: CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
   DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:146 - Connection established 10.1.209.211:49163<->155.70.58.219:443
   MainClientExec:256 - Executing request POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1
   MainClientExec:261 - Target auth state: CHALLENGED
   MainClientExec:267 - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
   headers:133 - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 92
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: devint.test.intranet
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_102)
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
   headers:136 - http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: Basic RVNMQ1hHNzpvVnlGUjNFNXMxQU41NnBJTXFOSCE=
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 92[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: devint.test.intranet[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_102)[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "Authorization: Basic RVNMQ1hHNzpvVnlGUjNFNXMxQU41NnBJTXFOSCE=[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
   wire:87 - http-outgoing-0 >> "{"payLoad":{"REQUEST":{"PROCESS_NM":"GetOrdersHierarchy"},"ITEMS":{"0":{"ORDER_ID":"ABC1"}}}}"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "L7-Policy-URL: https://devint.test.intranet:443/ssg/policy/disco?serviceoid=83f02502063fbaf43344f0c0888e3821[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 582[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:30:20 GMT[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "    <soapenv:Body>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "        <soapenv:Fault>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "            <faultstring>Policy Falsified</faultstring>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "            <faultactor>https://devint.test.intranet/X/Y/052ABC/ServicesDEV</faultactor>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "            <detail>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "                <l7:policyResult status="Authentication Required" xmlns:l7="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "            </detail>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "        </soapenv:Fault>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "    </soapenv:Body>[\n]"
   wire:73 - http-outgoing-0 << "</soapenv:Envelope>[\n]"
   headers:122 - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << L7-Policy-URL: https://devint.test.intranet:443/ssg/policy/disco?serviceoid=83f02502063fbaf43344f0c0888e3821
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 582
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:30:20 GMT
   headers:125 - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: close
   HttpAuthenticator:86 - Authentication succeeded
Test 4 First Response: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, L7-Policy-URL: https://devint.test.intranet:443/ssg/policy/disco?serviceoid=83f02502063fbaf43344f0c0888e3821, Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 582, Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2017 02:30:20 GMT, Connection: close] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8,Content-Length: 582,Chunked: false]}}
```

Comment: Are you missing `L7-Policy-URL` header along with your request?

Comment: I am not setting it anywhere. I thought it comes with response header. Both SOAPUI & App Logs show it.

Comment: I am getting the same error when trying to connect to a partners REST API. Did you ever solve this problem? @vivek4348